# is "if i knew you were ill , i would have visited you" grammatically correct?

Tags: past-simple, future-perfect

i wanted to know if it's okay to use future perfect (using WOULD not  WILL) with Past Simple.
i wanted to say if i knew he was ill at a point in the past , i will visit him at this point in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's understandable, but not quite the normal verb tense you'd want to use.

Instead, it would more commonly be:

> If I **had known** you were ill, I **would have** visited you.

That describes a past hypothetical.

---

For a present hypothetical:

> If I **knew** you were ill, I **would** visit you.

And for the future:

> If I **know** you are ill, I **will** visit you.